# Programmatically scroll as little distance as possible in Linux

Tags: linux, scripting, mouse, scrolling

I'm working on an autoscroll script for Linux and I'm trying to find a way to scroll as little distance as possible. I know I can generate mouse events using *uinput* (in particular, I can send `REL_WHEEL` events from a fake device in order to scroll) or Xorg-specific libraries, e.g. the *pynput* library for Python. The problem is that the distance scrolled by one mouse event is too big for my script to work smoothly at low speed.

What I've thought of so far:

- sending `REL_WHEEL_HI_RES` events instead of `REL_WHEEL`
- creating a fake touchpad device and generating scroll events from it

The first doesn't work - the events are generated correctly but nothing happens.
The second is probably not possible.

Comment: maybe you could ask `how to programmatically change the scroll distance in Linux?`

Comment: Instead of scroll wheel events, would it work to send down/up arrow events?

Comment: @glennjackman Scrolling by down/up arrow keys is the same as scrolling with the wheel. A single press corresponds to a single fixed-distance scroll event.

Comment: If you can get a reference to the GUI, maybe you can set the position of the scroll bar in smaller increments - without emulating input devices

Comment: In X11, you can check xdotool which allows a lot of things related to mouse or keyboard.

Comment: @A.B Unfortunately, there is nothing you can do with xdotool that you can't do with the methods I mentioned.